# i couldnt find the bug in my code. its giving an error for this test case [0,0][0,1]

Tags: java, arraylist

https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/5056/any-shorter-o-1-space-solution
I took this c++ solution from here and tried converting it into java

```
public void setZeroes(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a) {
    int colzero = 1;

    int rows = a.size();
    int cols = a.get(0).size();

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        if (a.get(i).get(0) == 0)
            colzero = 0;

        for (int j = 1; j < cols; j++)
        {
            if (a.get(i).get(j) == 0)
                a.get(i).set(0, 0);
            a.get(0).set(j, 0);
        }
    }

    for (int i = rows - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = cols - 1; j >= 1; j--) {
            if (a.get(i).get(0) == 0 || a.get(0).get(j) == 0)
                a.get(i).set(j, 0);
        }
        if (colzero == 0)
        {
            a.get(i).set(0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: Shall we guess the error?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

you need curly braces around your if block because you have split it into two instructions (there was only one in C++).

```
if(a.get(i).get(j)==0) {
            a.get(i).set(0,0);
            a.get(0).set(j,0);
}
```